# Is my punctuation correct?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, commas

I wrote a sentence, but I have my doubts that the punctuation in it is wrong. Please help me fix it.

Here's the sentence:

> "First, comment, then see what others commented."

Explain what's wrong and if it's correct, please explain that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need substitute a semicolon for your comma after "comment," to replace that comma that ungrammatically splices two main, independent clauses. Another reason a semicolon is needed after "comment" is that your first clause has a prior, internal comma.